# How can I find the right size box for each product?

Tags: sql, oracle, logistics

I am sorry for re-uploading this quesiton, but I really want the answer.

Kindly allow me to ask this question again and hope your kind support.

---

The question is to find the right size box which allow the logistic business to save the money when shipping.

We have 2 tables which are boxes and products.

Boxes table contains each ID and dimensions per box.
'w' for wide, 'd' for depth and 'h' for height. Please assume we have just 3 box samples for our convenience.

Products table includes also product ID, dimensions. Dimensions has the same meaning as boxes table.
'layable' means the product can be packaged not only straight position but also layable position. For instance product 'g' is a fragile bottle not being able to put horizontal position in the box. Thus this is 'n' in layable column.

This question needs to query each product ID with the right size box.
The right size box means the product needs to be shipped with box that is the least space.

Hope your kind help. Thanks.

boxes:

| BOX_SIZE | W | D | H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| S | 353 | 250 | 25 |
| M | 450 | 350 | 160 |
| L | 610 | 460 | 460 |

products:

| ID | W | D | H | LAYABLE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 350 | 250 | 25 | y |
| b | 450 | 250 | 160 | y |
| c | 510 | 450 | 450 | y |
| d | 350 | 250 | 25 | y |
| e | 550 | 350 | 160 | y |
| f | 410 | 400 | 430 | n |
| g | 350 | 240 | 25 | n |
| h | 450 | 350 | 160 | n |
| i | 310 | 360 | 430 | n |
| j | 500 | 500 | 600 | y |

Expected output:

| ID | BOX_SIZE |
| --- | --- |
| a | S |
| b | M |
| ... | .... |
| ... | .... |
| ... | .... |
| g | S |
| h | M |
| i | L |
| j | not available |

Statements to create and populate the tables for testing:

```
create table boxes
    ( box_size char(1) primary key
    , w        number  not null
    , d        number  not null
    , h        number  not null
    )
;

insert into boxes (box_size, w, d, h) values ('S', 353, 250,  25);
insert into boxes (box_size, w, d, h) values ('M', 450, 350, 160);
insert into boxes (box_size, w, d, h) values ('L', 610, 460, 460);

create table products
    ( id      varchar2(10) primary key
    , w       number       not null
    , d       number       not null
    , h       number       not null
    , layable char(1)      check(layable in ('y', 'n'))
    )
;

insert into products (id, w, d, h, layable) values ('a', 350, 250,  25, 'y');
insert into products (id, w, d, h, layable) values ('b', 450, 250, 160, 'y');
insert into products (id, w, d, h, layable) values ('c', 510, 450, 450, 'y');
insert into products (id, w, d, h, layable) values ('d', 350, 250,  25, 'y');
insert into products (id, w, d, h, layable) values ('e', 550, 350, 160, 'y');
insert into products (id, w, d, h, layable) values ('f', 410, 400, 430, 'n');
insert into products (id, w, d, h, layable) values ('g', 350, 240,  25, 'n');
insert into products (id, w, d, h, layable) values ('h', 450, 350, 160, 'n');
insert into products (id, w, d, h, layable) values ('i', 310, 360, 430, 'n');
insert into products (id, w, d, h, layable) values ('j', 500, 500, 600, 'y');    

commit;
```

Comment: Interesting question! I think I understand the "layable vs non-layable" business; for non-layable items, width and depth are interchangeable but not height, while for layable items all three dimenstions are interchangeable. Then, you talk about "least space"; how is that defined? I would guess least VOLUME, but I see no volume calculation in your query.

Comment: I edited your question, adding `create table` and `insert` statements to re-create the data for testing. Images like you posted look nice, but are not very helpful; please make a habit of providing the data in the format I added. (If **in addition** to that you also add tables in your format, that is probably the best option.) Note also that I changed the column name **size** to **box_size**, since **size** is a reserved keyword in Oracle; it shouldn't be used as table or column name.

Comment: Back to "least space" - I think I understand. In your case, box sizes S, M, L have ALL dimenstions in strictly increasing order, so there is no ambiguity. Use S if possible, if not then use M if possible, or if that isn't possible either, use L. Or report "not available".

Comment: One more note - I edited your question further, to add one more product that doesn't fit in ANY box. Your test data should always contain such special cases. (You even mentioned this possibility, you just didn't include an example in your sample.)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed comments. All look clear and reasonable. I should have made `create table` with data for testing. By 'least space' you understood well what I tried to explain. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key, of course, is the join between the two tables. I show it separately first, rather than the complete query, to help understanding. For each item, we find ALL the box sizes that can accommodate the item.

In all cases, the match is possible if product height <= box height, and the other two dimensions fit, in either permutation (products can always be **rotated** to fit in the box, whether they are layable or not).

Only for layable products, we are allowed to rotate the product in all three dimensions to fit them in boxes. This means that, for layable products only, we can compare product width or depth to box height, and compare the two remaining dimensions of the product to box width and depth.

Once we understand what I just said (as the way we would do this without computers, just with pencil on paper), the translation into code is almost automatic:

```
select p.id, b.box_size
from   products p left outer join boxes b
       on
            p.h <= b.h and least   (p.w, p.d) <= least   (b.w, b.d)
                       and greatest(p.w, p.d) <= greatest(b.w, b.d)
       or
       p.layable = 'y'
          and
          ( p.w <= b.h and least   (p.h, p.d) <= least   (b.w, b.d)
                       and greatest(p.h, p.d) <= greatest(b.w, b.d)
            or
            p.d <= b.h and least   (p.w, p.h) <= least   (b.w, b.d)
                       and greatest(p.w, p.h) <= greatest(b.w, b.d)
          )
;
```

Output:

```
ID  BOX_SIZE
--- --------
a   S       
a   M       
a   L       
b   M       
b   L       
c   L       
d   S       
d   M       
d   L       
e   L       
f   L       
g   S       
g   M       
g   L       
h   M       
h   L       
i   L       
j
```

For each product, we found ALL the sizes that would work.

Notice the outer join in the query, to include products that don't fit in ANY box size; that is the case of product `j`, which appears at the end of the output. Note that I use `null` as a marker for "***not available***" - the words "not available" add no valuable information over the simple use of `null`.

The next step is a simple aggregation - for each product, find the smallest size that works. The best tool for this is the `FIRST` aggregate function (as used below). We must order by box size; since the sizes are S, M, L (which are in reverse alphabetical order just by accident), I use the `decode()` function to assign 1 to S, 2 to M, 3 to L. The aggregate query finds the "first" size that works for each product.

The important thing here is that the query can be generalized easily to any number of possible "box sizes" - even when not all three dimensions are in increasing order. (You could also have boxes with only one of the dimensions very large while the others are small, etc.). You can order by box volume, or you can **store in the boxes table** an order of preference, equivalent to what I do in the query with the `decode()` function.

In the end, the query and output look like this. Note that I used `nvl()` in the `select` clause to generate `'not available'` for the last item, in case you really need it (which I doubt, but it's not my business problem.)

```
select p.id, 
       nvl(  min(b.box_size) keep (dense_rank first 
             order by decode(b.box_size, 'S', 1, 'M', 2, 'L', 3))
          , 'not available') as box_size
from   products p left outer join boxes b
       on
            p.h <= b.h and least   (p.w, p.d) <= least   (b.w, b.d)
                       and greatest(p.w, p.d) <= greatest(b.w, b.d)
       or
       p.layable = 'y'
          and
          ( p.w <= b.h and least   (p.h, p.d) <= least   (b.w, b.d)
                       and greatest(p.h, p.d) <= greatest(b.w, b.d)
            or
            p.d <= b.h and least   (p.w, p.h) <= least   (b.w, b.d)
                       and greatest(p.w, p.h) <= greatest(b.w, b.d)
          )
group  by p.id
;

ID  BOX_SIZE
--- --------
a   S       
b   M       
c   L       
d   S       
e   L       
f   L       
g   S       
h   M       
i   L       
j   not available
```

Comment: Hi @Mathguy, I really appreciate your hard work here. I am really impressived by your code, output and your deep understanding on my tough explanation. All your explanation look easily understandable and logical. And the codes such as decode and NVL could be adopted in my real business problem because I just put the data in simple way, but in reality it should be developed further. Thus I must say that your understanding and interpretation were so fantastic. Again thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

So far I can come up with my own answer as below, but this seems to get some triple rows per each product ID. Thus this needs to filter to the smallest box per query. I tired to use min(function) but this leads error.

```
select p.id, p.h, p.w, p.d, p.layable, case
when p.layable = 'n' then case 
 when p.h <= b.h and 
((greatest(p.w, p.d ) <= greatest(b.w, b.d)) 
and (least(p.w, p.d) <= least(b.w, b.d))) then b.id
else 'no' end
when p.layable = 'y' then case 
when (p.h + p.w + p.d) <= (b.h + b.w + b.d) and 
((greatest(p.h, p.w, p.d) <= greatest(b.h, b.w, b.d))
and (least(p.h, p.w, p.d) <= least(b.h, b.w, b.d))) then b.id
else 'no' end
 else 'not available' end
from products p, boxes b
order by p.id;
```

Comment: The conditions in the layable case are incorrect. Satisfying the conditions for the least and the greatest dimensions, and the SUM of dimentions, does not guarantee the inequality for the remaining dimension. Here is an easy counter-example: item dimenstions are 3, 7 and 10, and the box dimensions are 4, 6 and 20. 3 <=4 and 10 <= 20 and the sums are 20 <= 26, but this item will NOT fit in this box.